# Check if string is formatted properly

Tags: javascript, regex

Before doing POST request, I want to check if it has the right format.

```
var string = "HelloThomas!";
```

Proper format: `"Hello" + anything + "!"`

This string should return true cause it meets the condition.

Comment: `string.match(/^Hello.+!/)`?

Comment: `^Hello.*!$`???

Comment: Could be simply `/^Hello.+!$/`, although you need to be very careful with the "anything" part. By the way, there's a good tool for testing regular expressions: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @CRice that matches `Bonjour, Hello sir! How are you?`

Comment: @ctwheels Indeed. Add a `^` to the front to prevent that. I've edited my comment to include it.

Comment: The above comments will work but if you want to learn some regex for yourself I recommend going here for starters. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Comment: Should add `$` to the end too (it should appear the same as mine or @RishatMuhametshin's)

Comment: I can no longer edit the comment it seems. Perhaps post yours as an answer? Although I'm uncertain if OP meant for anything to include nothing (`.+` vs `.*`).

Comment: Ya I'm not sure either, I assumed *anything* meant `.*`, but I could be wrong. It wasn't explicitly stated. It seems The fourth bird beat me to my answer, oh well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/MuiRTd/1):

```
string.match(/^Hello.*!$/)
```